# Outlook VBA not returning CurrentUser Recipient object on some Windows 10 machines

Tags: vba, outlook, namespaces, windows-10

My work have started to roll out a new set of Lenovo ThinkCentre Windows 10 PCs. The issue is that on some models (but not all) my attempt to get the user's email address from Outlook fails due to Application.Session.CurrentUser not containing any information. If I could figure out a solution to this or a different method of obtaining the email address then I would be happy.

Here is the code that worked fine until they started installing new computers a few weeks ago:

```
Dim outApp As Object, outSession As Object

Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set outSession = outApp.Session.CurrentUser ' BREAKS HERE
currentuserEmailAddress = outSession.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress

Set outApp = Nothing
End Function
```

On these new systems, attempting to run the code will throw **runtime error 287** at the commented line. Adding outApp to the watchlist on a newer system shows that the CurrentUser object is null. On my PC I can expand out the CurrentUser object to see its properties, etc. but on the newer ones it is not expandable and just shows "<>" under the Value column.

I've raised a question with our tech support guys, but I had to explain to them the difference between a VGA cable and a DisplayPort cable the other day, so I'm not holding my breath there.

Comment: Do you have any accounts in Outlook configured?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check out the `Accounts` collection instead:

```
Namespace.Accounts.Item(1).SmtpAddress
```

Anyway, the `runtime error 287` states that you triggered a security issue when dealing with the Outlook object model. To bridge the gap with the security issues you can:

1. Use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. Also, you may consider using any third-party wrappers around this API such as Redemption.
2. Use components designed for turning off such issues. See [Security Manager for Microsoft Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php).
3. Set up any valid antivirus software.
4. Deploy a group policy to suppress such triggers in the OOM.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Session` can be null until you log to a profile. Change your code to

```
Dim outApp As Object, outSession As Object, outNamespace
Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set outNamespace = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
outNamespace.Logon

Set outSession = outApp.Session.CurrentUser
```

Also keep in mind that `GetExchangeUser()` can return null for a non-Exchange user - your need to check for that.